# Get the class tags using file_get_contents

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

I'm working on my PHP script to parse the html web page. I'm using `file_get_contents` to open the url to get the list of contents.

Here's the code:

```
$links = $row['links'];
$result = file_get_contents($links);
$html_content = str_replace("<a id='rowTitle1' class", "<a id='rowTitle1' class",$result);
print $html_content;
```

Here's the html output:

```
<li class="zc-ssl-pg" id="row1-1" style="">
<span id="row1Time" class="zc-ssl-pg-time">6:00 PM</span>
<a id="rowTitle1" class="zc-ssl-pg-title" href='http://www.mysite.com'>The Middle</a>
<a class="zc-ssl-pg-ep" href='http://www.mysite.com'>"Thanksgiving IV"</a>
```

Can you please tell me how I can get the values from the row1Time, rowTitle1 and the zc-ssl-pg-ep tags tags in the row1-1 class using with file_get_contents?

Comment: Not sure the reason you're replacing a string with itself there. preg_match is your friend in this case.

Comment: I'd be inclined to load the HTML into DOMDocument and do any manipulation in there. Parsing HTML using regular expressions can get quite tricky.

Comment: @halfer, its allright, as long as the HTML is quite static

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions are *not* the right tool for parsing HTML. The DOM is the right tool for that job:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($result);
echo $dom->getElementById('row1Time')->nodeValue . "<br>";
echo $dom->getElementById('rowTitle1')->nodeValue . "<br>";
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(1)->nodeValue;
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0YYJKJ)

This is still a little bit iffy because of how the HTML is structured but if it isn't going to change this will work.

Comment: @John Conde thanks for that, I have a problem with using your code. I have got an error which it is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$dom' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Check the code above mine. There's probably a semi-colon missing.

Comment: @JohnConde I have checked your code and i got it working, but the page is show as empty. I have only got is "<br><br>" in the html source. The content I want to output is 6:00 PM, The Middle and "Thanksgiving IV"

Comment: Is the html you posted *all* of the html to be parsed?

Comment: yeah that's what i really want to be parsed.

Comment: As the PHP fiddle shows it works so we need to figure out what's different between your code and mine. Can you echo out `$result` and verify it contains the HTML you expect?

Comment: I have got the full html contains using with file_get_contents.

Comment: Now I have got an error when i echo the html contains: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 725 in /home/username/public_html/myscript.php on line 36

Comment: Sounds like the html isn't quite valid. Can you post the entire html output so i can see what it looks like?

Comment: I have only got "<br>", maybe you have post invalid source. can you please update the correct source that i should use?

Comment: I tried to use: $links = $row['links'];
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($links);
    echo $dom->getElementById('row1Time')->nodeValue . "<br>"; it don't work

Comment: If you click on the link I provided it *clearly* works. If this isn't working for you then something is wrong on *your end*. I strongly suspect the HTML you posted here isn't exactly what you are getting on your end.

Comment: i have clicked on the link you provided. i can see that you did not post the code how i can get the content from the tag, e.g: $string ='<li class="zc-ssl-pg" id="row1-1" style="">
<span id="row1Time" class="zc-ssl-pg-time">6:00 PM</span>
<a id="rowTitle1" class="zc-ssl-pg-title" href=\'http://www.mysite.com\'>The Middle</a>
<a class="zc-ssl-pg-ep" href=\'http://www.mysite.com\'>"Thanksgiving IV"</a>';

Comment: I did. You can even see it on the page right above the code.

Comment: I want to know how i can get the content from the tag when i have the output in the php: http://tvlistings.zap2it.com/tvlistings/ZCSGrid.do?stnNum=10093

Comment: I think this might just be too far over your head right now. Everything you need is in the code I posted. Literally *everything*.

Answer (score 2):

```
$links = $row['links'];
$result = file_get_contents($links);
// $html_content = str_replace("<a id='rowTitle1' class", "<a id='rowTitle1' class",$result); // thats useless !

preg_match('/<span id="row1Time" class="zc-ssl-pg-time">([^<]+)<\/span>/', $html_content, $matches);
$row1Time = $matches[1];

preg_match('/<a id="rowTitle1" class="zc-ssl-pg-title" href='http:\/\/www\.mysite\.com'>([^<]+)<\/a>/', $html_content, $matches);
$rowTitle1 = $matches[1];

print $html_content;
```